# How to fetch data from an api handler from another api handler in Nextjs?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

Using Nextjs, I am struggling with fetching data from an API handler in another API handler. 
`/api/batch.js` handler retrieves some data from a MongoDB:

```
import middleware from '../../libs/mongodb';
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

const handler = nextConnect();
handler.use(middleware);
handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  const {batch_uuid} = req.query
  const batch_stats = await req.db.collection('stats').find({
    'batch.uuid': uuid
  }).toArray()
  res.json(batch_stats)  
})
export default (req, res) => handler.apply(req, res)
```

`/api/stats.js` handler retrieves some data from MySQL and, based on that and on data from Mongo, it builds a payload.

A dirty fix works as below in `stats.js`:

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/batch?uuid=1234')
const data = await response.json()
// use data and build another payload
```

However, this requires doing an http call and it does not make sense to do it for an internal endpoint.
I tried calling the `batch` handler dirrectly, but getting `undefined`

```
const getBatch = require('./batch');
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
   const accounts = await getBatch()
   res.status(200).json({accounts})
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract fetching data from the database to a separate module and import this module in both API handlers. Instead of one API endpoint making request to another API endpoint, API handlers would just use the same module that fetches data from MongoDB.

Comment: I actually did this, it's just slightly more ureadable because the database connection is also a middleware, part of the `req` object

Comment: @vicusbass, I had the similar issue. I have MongoDB middleware that I use in API requests. I extracted the connecting to DB part into separate module as well. In short my middleware look like `req.db = await mongo(); return handler(req, res);`. So, I can use MongoDB connection in API handlers as a middleware and in other parts of the app.

Comment: And you still have a single connection to Mongo?

Comment: @vicusbass, yeah, you even can share a single connection between different API requests. `MongoClient` class has a function `isConnected()`. So, you can check whether the client is already connected before making a new connection.